# Single user rvm needs sudo, and adding users to rvm group

Tags: installation, ruby, rvm

I am following the instructions on the [rvm site](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/). First, I tried to install for single users:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0     35      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   280
100  9439  100  9439    0     0   1602      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 30642
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/share/ruby-rvm': Permission denied
```

Are the instructions on the site wrong? Can someone on the rvm team either correct their install file or change the directions?

Then, I tried the multi-user install

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0     36      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   298
100  9439  100  9439    0     0    864      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 23192
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0    199      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   441
100 1046k  100 1046k    0     0   198k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  262k

Installing RVM to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/
    RVM system user group 'rvm' exists, proceeding with installation.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm/
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /usr/share/ruby-rvm/ is almost complete:

  * First you need to add all users that will be using rvm to 'rvm' group,
    and logout - login again, anyone using rvm will be operating with `umask g+w`.

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# big,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne


rvm 1.14.11 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

I am a little suspicious because the directions didn't mention anything about adding users. Where are the directions for adding users to the rvm group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of RVM packaged by Ubuntu is old and broken in mysterious ways, you need to read this for details how to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756